# flutter error: better_player causing error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-video-player

gradle file

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "org.mycwc"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:latest.release'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'
    implementation ('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.1')

}
```

### This is a error coming

```
D/AudioManager(30420): getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420): java.lang.NullPointerException: MediaSource.Factory#setDrmSessionManagerProvider no longer handles null by instantiating a new DefaultDrmSessionManagerProvider. Explicitly construct and pass an instance in order to retain the old behavior.
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420):   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Assertions.checkNotNull(Assertions.java:174)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420):   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaSource$Factory.setDrmSessionManagerProvider(ProgressiveMediaSource.java:186)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420):   at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayer.buildMediaSource(BetterPlayer.kt:430)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420):   at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayer.setDataSource(BetterPlayer.kt:196)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420):   at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.setDataSource(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:277)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420):   at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.onMethodCall(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:151)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420):   at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.onMethodCall(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:138)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
E/MethodChannel#better_player_channel(30420):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
E/flutter (30420): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, MediaSource.Factory#setDrmSessionManagerProvider no longer handles null by instantiating a new DefaultDrmSessionManagerProvider. Explicitly construct and pass an instance in order to retain the old behavior., null, java.lang.NullPointerException: MediaSource.Factory#setDrmSessionManagerProvider no longer handles null by instantiating a new DefaultDrmSessionManagerProvider. Explicitly construct and pass an instance in order to retain the old behavior.
E/flutter (30420):  at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Assertions.checkNotNull(Assertions.java:174)
E/flutter (30420):  at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaSource$Factory.setDrmSessionManagerProvider(ProgressiveMediaSource.java:186)
E/flutter (30420):  at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayer.buildMediaSource(BetterPlayer.kt:430)
E/flutter (30420):  at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayer.setDataSource(BetterPlayer.kt:196)
E/flutter (30420):  at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.setDataSource(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:277)
E/flutter (30420):  at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.onMethodCall(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:151)
E/flutter (30420):  at com.jhomlala.better_player.BetterPlayerPlugin.onMethodCall(BetterPlayerPlugin.kt:138)
E/flutter (30420):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/flutter (30420):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/flutter (30420):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/flutter (30420):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source)
E/flutter (30420):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
E/flutter (30420):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/flutter (30420):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
E/flutter (30420):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
E/flutter (30420):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (30420):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
E/flutter (30420):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
E/flutter (30420): )
E/flutter (30420): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
E/flutter (30420): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:296:18)
E/flutter (30420): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (30420): #2      MethodChannelVideoPlayer.setDataSource (package:better_player/src/video_player/method_channel_video_player.dart:118:5)
E/flutter (30420): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (30420): #3      VideoPlayerController._setDataSource (package:better_player/src/video_player/video_player.dart:408:5)
E/flutter (30420): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (30420): #4      BetterPlayerController._setupDataSource (package:better_player/src/core/better_player_controller.dart:444:9)
E/flutter (30420): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (30420): #5      BetterPlayerController.setupDataSource (package:better_player/src/core/better_player_controller.dart:274:5)
E/flutter (30420): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (30420): 
I/ExoPlayerImpl(30420): Release b949e61 [ExoPlayerLib/2.18.1] [santoni, Redmi 4, Xiaomi, 25] [goog.exo.core, goog.exo.exoplayer, goog.exo.decoder]
```

Comment: @Dharini I have removed video_player plugin then it worked fine

Comment: thanks it solved ,In my code just_audio & video_player both conflict with better_player